# SQL I dont want to have names like alfred or Alfred or alfr in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, check-constraint

This is what I tried to do but it doesn't work :

```
ALTER TABLE DEPT
ADD CONSTRAINT DEPT_DNAME_CK CHECK (DNAME = 'ALF%');
```

Comment: Are you using oracle 10g or greater?

Comment: USING THIS Version 4.0.3.16

Comment: Oracle is case sensitive may be `upper(dname) like 'ALF%'`

Comment: in the end i dont want to be able to enter upper or lower or similar  names in the table. the answer below gave me this error:ORA-02293

Comment: That error is constraint `ORA-02290: check constraint` violation error. If you have below check constraint and insert a data that violate the constraint, then you get this error.

Comment: Do you want to prevent anything starting with 'alf' (in any case), or allow a single value and prevent a second similar value being inserted? It also isn't clear if only 'alf' needs to be restricted, or anything with similar first three characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow a single value but then not anything similar - where 'similar' here seems to be starting with the same first three letters, in any case - you can use a unique function-based index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNQ_DNAME_START ON DEPT (UPPER(SUBSTR(DNAME, 1, 3)));

Unique index UNQ_DNAME_START created.
```

Then you can have one value:

```
INSERT INTO DEPT (DNAME) VALUES ('Alfred');

1 row inserted.
```

But attempting to insert a second similar value will error:

```
INSERT INTO DEPT (DNAME) VALUES ('alfonso');

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA.UNQ_DNAME_START) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

I'm assuming that you've only used 'alf%' as an example, and you actually want to prevent all similar entries, not that specific prefix.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some entries in the column `dname` like `alf%`, you have to delete the entries before you add the constraint.

```
create table dept (dname varchar(250));
insert into dept select 'alflll' from dual;
alter table dept add constraint dept_dname_ck check (lower(dname) not like 'alf%');
```

you get an error;

```
ORA-02293: cannot validate (*****.DEPT_DNAME_CK) - check constraint violated
```

now delete the entries:

```
delete from dept where lower(dname) like 'alf%';
alter table dept add constraint dept_dname_ck check (lower(dname) not like 'alf%');
```

After you enable this constraint, if you try to violate the constraint you get an error:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (****.DEPT_DNAME_CK) violated